# Macка на адрес с

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

Нужно что-то подобное `.mask("(999) 999-9999")`
Я нашла такую ссылку https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask 
у меня ничего не получилось

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#example1").inputmask("99-9999999");
  $("#example2").inputmask("Regex");
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input id="example1" data-inputmask-clearmaskonlostfocus="false" />
      <input id="example2" data-inputmask-regex="[a-za-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?" />
    </body>
 </html>
```

В данном поле (оно не редактируемое!) отображается слово `Regex`.

пробую другое в полях указываем регулярное выражение.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#example1").inputmask("aa-9{4}");  //static mask with dynamic syntax отображается  __-_{4} 
  $("#example2").inputmask("aa-9{1,4}");  //dynamic mask ~ the 9 def can be occur 1 to 4 times - отображается  __-_{1,4} , {} -не работают

  //email mask отображается регулярное выражение, указанное в mask
  $("#example3").inputmask({
    mask: "*{1,20}[.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}]@*{1,20}[.*{2,6}][.*{1,2}]",
    greedy: false,
    onBeforePaste: function (pastedValue, opts) {
      pastedValue = pastedValue.toLowerCase();
      return pastedValue.replace("mailto:", "");
    },
    definitions: {
      '*': {
        validator: "[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\-]",
        cardinality: 1,
        casing: "lower"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input id="example1" />
      <input id="example2" />
      <input id="example3" />
    </body>
 </html>
```